# How to make this C code shorter

Tags: c

I have some code that toggles values in a `struct`.

For example, I find myself writing code a lot that looks like this:

```
if(options.test == 1)
{
    options.test = 2;
}
else if (options.test == 2)
{
    options.test = 1;
}
```

Is there a more compact version I can use to make this code shorter?

Comment: You are using the comparsion operator '==' inside the brackets. I guess you want an assignment '='?

Comment: If you have only 2 states, you can use an int like a bool instead and just use 'value' and '!value'. The other solution would be a switch statement.

Comment: Don't sacrifice readability, don't use magic numbers, and don't repeat yourself. Consider writing a function to do this check-and-invert instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run A and then B or run C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627707/run-a-and-then-b-or-run-c)

Comment: A very short (& even less readable) code: `options.test ^= 3;`

Answer (score 8):

If the values of `options.test` are either 1 or 2 throughout the execution of your program, then you can simply do:

```
options.test = 3-options.test;
```

If this variable may be set to other values, then the best way to handle it is usually with:

```
switch (options.test)
{
    case 1:   options.test = 2;   break;
    case 2:   options.test = 1;   break;
    case ...: options.test = ...; break;
    case ...: options.test = ...; break;
    case ...: options.test = ...; break;
    default:  options.test = ...; break;
}
```

If the values are between 0 and N (with a relatively small N), then you may also consider hashing.

For example, instead of:

```
switch (options.test)
{
    case 0: options.test = 4; break;
    case 1: options.test = 2; break;
    case 2: options.test = 1; break;
    case 3: options.test = 3; break;
    case 4: options.test = 5; break;
    case 5: options.test = 0; break;
}
```

You can do:

```
static int hash[] = {4,2,1,3,5,0};
options.test = hash[options.test];
```

Comment: I thought about suggesting this too, but boy would it make the code harder to read and maintain.

Comment: @Joe White, well - OP asks for a "shorter" way, right? (though just as you, I'm not really sure what would that gain)...

Comment: @barakmanos : yours code is indeedly shorter, but the OP didn't wrote in detail if his values are only 1 or 2. If it's 1 - 2, then yours answer is the way to go.

Comment: @KarelG, My answer says (and I quote): "If the values of options.test are either 1 or 2 throughout the execution of your program".

Comment: In this example my values are only 1 and 2. However, other code I have written uses more than just these two values. I was asking if there is a simple way to shorten it to make it easier to read.

Comment: @user9993: If you have other values, then the best way would probably be to use a `switch/case` statement.

Answer (score 2):

i would use a switch case block inside a method if you have multiple option values.

```
options.test = setOptionTestValue(options.test);
```

method

```
int setOptionTestValue(value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 1: return 2;
        case 2: return 1;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, although this fails a bit with the *shorter* criteria that OP asks about

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a fairly generic question rather than an exact example. I find that for these simple single line statements dropping the braces is still perfectly readable:

```
if(options.test == 1)
    options.test = 2;
else if (options.test == 2)
    options.test = 1;
```

Comment: @AxitSoni, where did OP ask for one line of code? The question was for *shorter* code. This totally qualifies.

Comment: sorry he edited. may be .. at first when i saw this question at that time it is there :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use ['switch'](http://home.fhtw-berlin.de/~junghans/cref/SYNTAX/switch.html) because it's more beautiful:

```
switch (options.test) {
   case 1:
      options.test = 2;
      break;
   case 2:
      options.test = 1;
      break;
}
```

If you have just this code and nothing more, use this:

```
options.test = 3 - options.test;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), especially since you said you've been writing this code repeatedly (once for each type of state transition?). What about making a function that returns the new state?

```
int getNewStateAfterLogin(int oldState) {
    switch (oldState) {
        case 1:
            return 2;
        case 2:
            return 1;
        default:
            return oldState;
    }
}

options.test = getNewStateAfterLogin(options.test);
```

Of course, if it really is a state machine, you'd want to use an enum, or symbolic constants at the very least. But this gives you a chance to pull the logic into a separate function, and give that function a name.

Answer (score 0):

For input `{1,2}`:

```
int map[3]  = {0, 2, 1};

options.test = map[options.test];
```

Adjust as needed for other/more input.